Use of secrets in Hibernate @ColumnTransformer annotation
Im trying to store column specific encryption password as a application.properties secret.
I tried:
@Value("${database.encrypt.secret}")
private String secret;

@ColumnTransformer(read = "TRIM(CHAR(0) FROM UTF8TOSTRING(DECRYPT('AES', HASH('SHA256', STRINGTOUTF8('" + secret + "'), 1), name)))", write = "ENCRYPT('AES', HASH('SHA256', STRINGTOUTF8('" + secret + "'), 1), STRINGTOUTF8(?))")
private String name;

but @ColumnTransformer read and write attributes requires a constant so i cant do anything like this.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Did you try a Custom Type ? or maybe follow this guide.
https://sultanov.dev/blog/database-column-level-encryption-with-spring-data-jpa/
